# How to set Eclipse Android SDK location to a relative path

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration, relative-path

I can set the Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location, however that does not allow editing it to a relative location (path that starts with ..\ instead of C:) - this setting should be stored in the config somewhere, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Is it configurable in the eclipse.ini file? if not, how can I set this to a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your Eclipse workspace, not the Eclipse install directory, but the workspace directory.  If you are not certain what that directory is, you can find it under "File > Switch Workspace > Other".

Given this directory, then go to the following file: .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs

This file contains the property that defines the SDK directory.  Here is a snippet from my file:

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.fixLegacyEditors=1
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.lintOnExport=false
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.lintOnSave=false
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.xmlEditor=true
design.structure.flyout.width=217
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked, but the file seems to be a different format that the eclispse.ini file - notable the \ need to be escaped with a \, so the path ended up looking like "..\\sdk"